# Swift: Computed Properties Using Same Getters And/Or Setters

Tags: swift, class

Everyone. I was wondering if it was possible in Swift to use the same property observers for multiple variables, without having to re-write them every time?

For example in this piece of Swift code below:

```
class Foo {
func setInfo() {
    //Do Something
}

var var1 = "" {
    didSet {
        setInfo()
    }
}

var var2 = "" {
    didSet {
        setInfo()
    }
}

var var3 = "" {
    didSet {
        setInfo()
    }
}
}
```

I have to write the same didSet-observer for every variable. Is there a way to write this shorter and without writing it over and over again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the properties represent? Depending on the use case you could put them in an array, dictionary, set or even a custom struct – and then put the setter observer on that wrapper. As long as the properties are value types, the setter observer will get triggered when you mutate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write observers in one line if you wish (so do I in short constructions), it looks more readable. But there is generally no other way.

```
class Foo {

    var var1 = "" {didSet {setInfo()}}
    var var2 = "" {didSet {setInfo()}}
    var var3 = "" {didSet {setInfo()}}

    func setInfo() {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I never really thought of just writing them in one line :)